# Language detection at shell command

Tags: text-processing, language, shell-scripting

I need to detect the language of a huge amount of files, and I was wondering if there is some tool which I could use in a way similar to this, in linux command shell:

```
langdetector filetodetect > detectedlangfile
```

Comment: Could you add more requirements for the proposed software? What environments does it needs to run? Command line only? Price/free? Anything that could be used to refine a search.

Comment: I've added "in linux command shell:" to the question, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org) can do that for 18 languages:
Danish, German, Estonian, Greek, English, Spanish, Finnish, French, Hungarian, Icelandic, Italian, Dutch, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Russian, Swedish and Thai

the command on linux would be:
java -jar tika-app-1.18.jar -l filetodetect > detectedlangfile 2>/dev/null

Comment: It wasn't at your list but it also detects Catalan which I also needed...

Comment: Yes, more languages are supported, but I can't seem to find an up to date list